# ¿Cómo hacer desaparecer (deshabilitar) el scroll del html?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Estoy tratando de esconder y a la vez deshabilitar el scroll del html; estoy usando material-ui para el diseño, utilizando un `backdrop` pero este mismo no deshabilita el scroll como lo hace un menú de material-ui. El menú de material-ui se abre y la página solo responde a la interacción con el menú; de escuchar un click fuera de este, el menú desaparece y el scroll vuelve a aparecer. El `backdrop` no tiene la misma función, este me deja hacer scroll al tener abierto el `backdrop` y eso es lo que trato de evitar.

Answer (score 1):

Si buscas prevenir el scroll de la página, puedes usar la propiedad `overlow` de CSS

```css
body, html {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Esto ocultará la barra (tanto horizontal como vertical) de la página

Si buscas esconder una sola barra de scroll, puedes optar por `overflow-x`, `overflow-y`

```css
body, html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* Prevenir scroll horizontal */
```

```css
body, html {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

/* Prevenir scroll vertical */
```

#### Puede ser de utilidad

- [CSS overflow-x property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp)
- [CSS overflow-y property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp)
- [CSS Overflow](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp)
- [CSS overflow property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)
- [CSS Overflow (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Comment: esto haria que el scroll desaparezca durante el ciclo de vida de la app, no es lo que busco, solo estoy tratando de ocultarlo y deshabilitarlo cuando un componente se este mostrando